# header location login error

Tags: php, redirect

I dont know whats the problem but
if user is logged in and visits mysite.com it redirects to mysite.com/memberarea.php properly without any errors but if user visits www.mysite.com he's not redirected :S .

im using this code :

> header('location: memberarea.php');

*update in detail

> require_once('config.php');
>   session_start();
>   if($_SESSION['in'] != 1)
>   {
>    //do something
>   }
>   }else{
>    header('location: memberarea.php');

memberarea.php code

> require_once('config.php');
>   session_start();
>   if($_SESSION['in'] != 1)
>   {
>    header('location: memberarea.php');
>   }
>   }else{ 
>   //do something
>   }

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're setting a cookie somewhere, for instance the session cookie, and it isn't set to apply to the entire domain but only the subdomain.  You could probably solve this problem by redirecting to `www.myweb.com` when a user visits `myweb.com`, or vice-versa.

EDIT: sample htaccess to force www.-

```
## Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, as mentioned above, you should use a full URI when using `header`.  So "http://www.myweb.com/whatever.php" rather than just "whatever.php".

Comment: @Chris , How should i do that?

Comment: I use htaccess to force www, edited answer to include the rule I use.

Comment: @chris i don't think that's what she wants done. i think she wants to redirect based on if a user is logged in or not

Comment: What I am saying is that it appears, for a reason I do not know because I haven't seen the entirety of the code, the session cookie (or a different user_id-related cookie) is set to only apply to the current sub-domain.  So if the user logs in on www.myweb.com, the cookie does not apply on myweb.com.  The easiest way to solve this without diving into the rest of the code is to simply restrict use of the site to one subdomain or another.  Admittedly, this does not SOLVE, it BYPASSES, but if doing so fixes the issue, then you know where to look further if you do want to SOLVE.  :)

Comment: @chris i know where u are going with this.  its all speculation and guessing without knowing the actual issue, is where i am trying to get at.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using two brackets before your "else"

```
if($session){
//do something
} else {
//do another thing
}
```

Try this and it will work!

Comment: I don't think the code in OP is the literal code in use... he mentioned that it works in certain circumstances.  Hardly possible if the problem is attributed to a syntax error!  :)